# How to limit write frequency to core.async channel?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is there an easy way to limit the write frequency to a core.async channel ? So far I could find two examples. One uses a sliding-buffer and some SetTimeout magic to handle this the other uses an external atom as a counter. I would have expected that core.async provides such functionality out of the box. Since one of the examples is rather old (10 month) I would like to know if theres is maybe an easier solution ?

I'm looking for a solution that works with Clojure and ClojureScript.

Comment: Puts on channels park if the buffer is full. Does a smaller buffer not work for your use case?

Answer (score 2):

The [throttler lib](https://github.com/brunoV/throttler) provides functions to impose rate controls on Clojure code (including throttles on channels or functions).

From the readme:

```
(def in (chan 1))
(def slow-chan (throttle-chan in 1 :millisecond)) ; 1 msg/ms

(>!! in :token) ; => true
(<!! slow-chan) ; :token
```

Comment: This lib doesn't work with ClojureScript. I edited my question to make it clearer that both Clojure and Clojure should be supported.

Comment: That's kind of a weak response as that little library looks extremely straightforward to port and expresses the key idea in just a few lines of code.

Comment: Nevertheless it is probably the Stack Overflow way to copy in the kernel of the idea into the answer (links go dead, yadda, yadda).

Comment: I'm now using the example from  https://gist.github.com/swannodette/5886048. My first attempt to use it failed. But now it is working.